# Defining Conic Section From 5 Points (No Matrix work)

Tags: conic-sections

I am doing a homework assignment, and I need to find:

**a)** what type of conic it is **b)** the equation for the conic

from $5$ points. In class we haven't done any work with matrices, so I need a method which does not use them.

Example problem: $(0,0), (1,5), (3,4), (2,0), (2,3)$

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you done any work yourself? It's been a long time since I've had to do this, but I know there are methods for drawing precise conic sections by hand by using a few tools. Look into stuff like directrix, focus, etc. The table on this page might help: http://math2.org/math/algebra/conics.htm

Comment: I have tried setting up "systems of equation" for the conic, and solving variables like that. Doesn't seem to be working that well..... Also, the points do not have to be the directrix or focus of it.

Comment: That system of equations is the way to solve the problem. Show your work; perhaps someone here will be able to help.

Comment: Your right. I made an algebra error. +/- whats the difference. Thanks.

Comment: actually this is wrong. To work out the algebra, you need to assume a variable is greater then 0 (which you can not)